# dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Invalid environment assignments

Tags: linux, dbus, sles

When I use MobaXterm to SSH into one of our SLES 15 LINUX server, I see below warnings always. How can I fix this warning? Please note that when I use Mac terminal or iTerm2 to SSH into this LINUX server, I don't see this warning.

`dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Invalid environment assignments`

Comment: I've the same problem. I think it is relatively irrelevant for the use and that "MAC terminal" and iTerm2 simply ignores the error.

Answer (score 0):

Same here.
Looks like there is a problem with the x11 forwarding.

Disable x11 forwarding in my bookmark workes for me for the moment.

Comment: I don't know if this answer is very helpful since "x11 forwarding" is just what the user intends and needs to use.

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work for me. However, I just posted how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are a couple of files that might call `dbus-update-activation-environment` on login.

`#==[ Configuration File ]===========================#`

`# /etc/profile.d/openssh-dbus.sh`

`if test -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" -a -n "$DISPLAY"`

`then`
`dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all`

`fi`

`#==[ Configuration File ]===========================#`

`# /etc/profile.d/openssh-dbus.csh`

`if ( ${?SSH_CONNECTION} && ${?DISPLAY} ) dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all`

After commenting those lines and trying out again the issue was resolved.